# use of Snowflake (json) variant storing data in streamlit

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, streamlit

I am storing a json object in a Variant Column in Snowflake, something like this and I am tryin to work this display as line chart

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "meter_timestamp": "2020-01-28T00:30:00",
            "meter_value": 3.109
        },
        {
            "meter_timestamp": "2020-01-28T01:00:00",
            "meter_value": 3.509
        },
        {
            "meter_timestamp": "2020-01-28T01:30:00",
            "meter_value": 1.109
        }
    ],
    "edm_profile": "A00017953",
    "valueday": "2020-01-28"
}

data_dict = json.loads(json_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict['data'])
# Convert timestamp to datetime
df['meter_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['meter_timestamp'])  
st.line_chart(df.set_index('meter_timestamp')['meter_value'])
```

I am unsure how do I go about using by actually connecting to the database and displaying this i.e. , this will create a pandas dataframe and then what I would like to use the json data stored in the variant format as much as possible . The below gives a dataframe or JSON Data in Variant columns is not support in Snowflake Streamlit Apps

```
df_table = session.table("sample_data")
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated